# Javascript doesn't match input value in speed typing

Tags: javascript

I am just trying to make a typing test project and for that I'm using javaScript. How i explain i don't know but the main thing i really want to say that i have a object call **keyTest** and its has many property among there is one property called **wordMatch** which has an array and the array was filled with many objects by **createWordObject** method. the objects look like this:

```
var keyTest = {
        wordMatch: [
            {
                "word" : "some",
                "match" : false,
                "matchingTime": 0
            },
            {
                "word" : "text",
                "match" : false,
                "matchingTime": 0
            },
            {
                "word" : "in",
                "match" : false,
                "matchingTime": 0
            },
            {
                "word" : "here",
                "match" : false,
                "matchingTime": 0
        },
    ],
}
```

now, **onkeyup** event i want to match the **input word** and **word property** one by one, if its matches i will update **match** property to *true* and get the timpStamp off the events. its work perfectly for me but i have to type slow in the input. if i type very speedly even if its match the **input word** with **property word** it just updated the **match property** to sometime false or sometime true.

i don't know how i explain but after watching this three image, everybody will understand what i really want to say. and also add link of my project.[see the link](http://skypaybd.org/)

Comment: Don't use the `keyup` event. Use the `input` event. And ALWAYS post the code you are working with/asking about in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing this with the help of regex and the oninput event handler for your text box :)

```js
window.onload = () => {
  let keyTest = {
    wordMatch: [
      {
        word: "some",
        match: false,
        matchingTime: 0
      },
      {
        word: "text",
        match: false,
        matchingTime: 0
      },
      {
        word: "in",
        match: false,
        matchingTime: 0
      },
      {
        word: "here",
        match: false,
        matchingTime: 0
      }
    ]
  };
  // the date object where we could get all our date related stuff
  let currDate = new Date();
  // our input field
  let textbox = document.getElementById('word-box');
  // our regex string
  let regEx = '';
  // the variable that will hold all the matched words found in the input field
  let matches = '';
  // the index of a given matched word in the wordMatch array
  let wordInd = -1;
  // build the regex string we're going to use to check if any of the words are keyed in
  keyTest.wordMatch.forEach((item, i) => {
    regEx += `${item.word}${i < keyTest.wordMatch.length - 1 ? "|" : ""}`;
  });
  // build the actual regExp which would be /(word 1|word 2|word 3|word 4)/g
  regEx = new RegExp(`(${regEx})`, 'g');
  // have our textbox listen for new inputs
  textbox.addEventListener("input", function() {
    // check the input field's value for any matches
    matches = this.value.match(regEx);
    if (matches) {
      matches.forEach(word => {
        // get the index of the word in the wordMatch array
        wordInd = keyTest.wordMatch.findIndex(words => words.word == word);
        // set the match property
        keyTest.wordMatch[wordInd].match = true;
        // set the matching date property
        keyTest.wordMatch[wordInd].matchingTime = `${currDate.getMonth() +
          1}/${currDate.getDate()}/${currDate.getFullYear()} @ ${currDate.getHours()}:${currDate.getMinutes()}`;
      });
    }
    
    // just to show that it does indeed set everything correctly
    matches ? console.log(keyTest.wordMatch[keyTest.wordMatch.findIndex(words => words.word == matches[matches.length - 1])]) : '';
  });
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="word-box"/>
```

Also, here's a [working example](https://codepen.io/RaysOfTheSun/pen/QJrjpd?editors=1011) and a reference to [`regExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) and [`oninput`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oninput) :)